# After running screen, screen doesn't seem to be running

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I use ssh to log into a remote machine
and then I use the `screen` command to create a virtual screen.

Now, if I type in `exit`
normally I should only exit the screen and return to the remote ssh terminal
but the reality is the `exit` command exits the ssh and I return to the local terminal. Why?

Besides, if I run a program/process in the virtual screen, I can't use 
`C-a d` to return to the remote ssh terminal, 
it just echoes back `^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^`, and doesn't return to the remote ssh terminal.

```
root@remote_lab:/home/esy# time bash test.sh  2>&1|cat > temp
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Describe what happens when you run `screen` (what appears on the screen and where). What terminal are you running in on your local machine? What does `echo $TERM` show locally, in the ssh session, and after running `screen`? What happens if you type `C-a ?` after running `screen`?

Comment: What you described sounds exactly like the behavior with no `screen` running, so I second @Gilles's question...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are in a `screen`?

If so, the `TERM` variable should look like this:

```
$ echo $TERM
screen-256color
```